# how to send data to server without showing it, in developer mode browser (inspect)?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, json

I want to hide the identity from get function in php,
I'm using xhr, to get the from server
it working fine but maiking too much requests to the server due to this, sometimes server is showing server down,

I have to hide the identity or message to which I'm sending to the server
Is there any way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't make a browser keep secrets from its owner.

If you want to make a request without the browser's owner knowing about it, make it from the server instead of using XHR.

Comment: Can I get any Example, if I have to make to send a message to the server like chatting application ? What if we use **WebSocket** rather than **XHR**

Comment: if  you are making a chatting application, then you need to get things the user is saying from the browser and things being said to the user to the browser. It makes no sense at all to try to keep these things secret from the user since they either originated from the user or need to be shown to them.

Comment: Web sockets are just another way to getting data to and from the browser. You still can't keep this information secret from the user  who controls the browser.